# How to add a n-dimensional constant Tensor to my model output in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

my model takes a batch of images as input and outputs a customized batch of images. During pre-processing, the VGG-16 mean pixel values are subtracted from each channel. This is necessary due to further processing. In order to evaluate the results, I want to add a custom Layer at the end of the model, in order to get the visual results. Therefore, this layer needs to add the subtracted values again.

So far, I wanted to use a Lambda layer, that wraps a function. In this function I tried to stack three constant-tensors in order to add this 3D tensor to the output. The problem I'm facing here is that I don't know the batch size nor the image size and the constant-tensors don't accept None as shape entries. How can I make this function suitable for an arbitrary input. Basically what I want to to is:

```py
    mean = [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]
    x[..., 0] += mean[0]
    x[..., 1] += mean[1]
    x[..., 2] += mean[2]
```

Code:

```py
    model_inp = Input(shape = (None , None , channels) , name='input')
        model_output = Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (9,9),padding ='same', activation ='relu', kernel_initializer= 'RandomNormal' )(model_inp)
    model_output = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (1,1),padding ='same', activation ='relu', kernel_initializer= 'RandomNormal' )(model_output)
    model_output = Conv2D(filters = 3, kernel_size = (5,5),padding ='same', activation ='linear', kernel_initializer= 'RandomNormal', name = 'output')(model_output)
    model_output_fin = Lambda(self.vgg_postprocessing)(model_output)



    def vgg_postprocessing(self, x):
        mean = [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]

        B = K.constant(mean[0], shape=(None,None,None,1))
        G = K.constant(mean[1], shape=(None,None,None,1))
        R = K.constant(mean[2], shape=(None,None,None,1))

        tens = K.stack([B,G,R],axis=3)
        x += tens
        return x
```